# A value of type "Future<Null>" can't be assigned to a variable of type "Data"

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, future

I'm trying figured out how to work with future for fetching data over internet. I was trying to write a simple code where I convert Future into "average" data but it doesn't work and I can't get why that's happend.

Here's my code

```
class Fetch {  
  Data getData () {
    Data data;
    data = fetch().then((value) {data = value;}); //here's I'm getting error
  }
  
  Future<Data> fetch() async {
    int number = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => 3);
    return(Data.fromIt(number));
  }
}


class Data{
  int date;
  
  Data({this.date});
  
  factory Data.fromIt(int num) {
    return Data(
      date: num,
    );
  }
}
```

After I corrected this part of code error has gone but now `getData()` returns null instead of value:

```
Data getData () {
  Data data;
  fetch().then((value) {data = value;});
  return data; //null
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `date = fetch().then(...)` means that you're trying to assign the `Future` returned by `Future.then()` to `data`.  You're already assigning `data = value` inside the `.then` callback, so the outer assignment makes no sense and is unnecessary.  Remove it.  Better yet, just use `async` and `await`, and it would be much clearer.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice it. But I'm still curious if is it possible to somehow extract data from future. I mean something like `void GetData ()  => futureFunc().then((value) => data = value));`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  There should be nothing stopping you from doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `getData` an **async function**, and use the `await` keyword. It is much easier to understand if you are new to async programming and `Futures`

```dart
Future<Data> getData () async {
    final data = await fetch();
    // Whatever you want to do with data
    return data; // Dont forget to return it back to the caller
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's not exactly what I want because now `getData()` returns "_Future<Data>" but I want it returns "Data"

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible. If your function relies on data from an async operation, it must return a Future type. This is because, by the time your function returns, the async operation hasn't completed yet, and the result you need is not yet available to return to the caller. You MUST return a `Future` instead

Answer (score 0):

The `data` is defined as a `Data` object, while `fetch()` returns a `Future<Data>`, causing the error.

```dart
Data data;
  data = fetch().then((value) {
    data = value;
  });
```

You can not transform a `Future` object to a synchronous object without awaiting it. You can do this at the UI to get the `Future` value:

```dart
FutureBuilder<Data>(
  future: Fetch().fetch(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();
    Data data = snapshot.data;
    return Text(data);
  },
)
```